# Add class to top-level ul using menu_block

Tags: 7, routes, blocks

I am using the Menu Block Module to generate my main and sub navs.  I want to add a class to the ul for **just the top level of the main nav**.

As I understand it, I can do something like this:

```
function theme_menu_tree__menu_block($variables) {
  return '<ul class="my classes">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

or this:

```
function theme_menu_tree__menu_block__main_menu($variables) {
  return '<ul class="my classes">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

**However, that seems to wrap every level of the navigation with the above html.  How can I restrict the modification to the first level?**

It doesn't look like I am given much data in `$variables`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8):

Here's the trick: theme_menu_tree__MENU_NAME() and theme_menu_link().

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements theme_menu_tree().
 */
function THEMENAME_menu_tree__MENU_NAME(&$variables) {
  return '<ul class="FIRST-LEVEL-CLASS">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}

/**
 * Implements theme_menu_link().
 */
function THEMENAME_menu_link__MENU_NAME(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  if ($element['#below']) {
    // Wrap in dropdown-menu.
    unset($element['#below']['#theme_wrappers']);
    $sub_menu = '<ul class="OTHER-LEVEL-CLASS">' . drupal_render($element['#below']) . '</ul>';
  }
  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: If I understand right, this should be implemented in template.php? Have been trying to get this working with no success yet..

Answer (score 1):

`$variables` gives me:

```
array(3) {
  ["tree"]=> string(n) "HTML for the sub-tree"
  ["theme_hook_suggestion"]=> string(n) "menu_tree__menu_block__main_menu"
  ["theme_hook_suggestions"]=> array(0) { }
}
```

It seems pretty bad, but I could do a string search to see if the menu contains the text for one of my top level elements:

```
<?php

function theme_menu_tree__menu_block__main_menu($variables) {
  if (!stripos($variables['tree'], 'home')) {
    return '<ul>' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
  } else {
    return '<ul class="my classes">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in this recent blog post regarding [themeing native menus in drupal by Webbykat](http://www.webbykat.com/2012/12/working-drupals-native-menu-system-instead-menu-blocks-remedial-course) (as opposed to menu_blocks). He is adding classes to `theme_links`, which your not trying to call. He's modifying the tpl file, but you could do this in `YOURTHEME_links__system_main_menu()` I believe. I've used this function as well, but offhand not to achieve this.

```
<?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array('links' => $main_menu, 'attributes' => array('id' => 'main-menu', 'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix', 'main-menu')), 'heading' => array('text' => t('Main menu'),'level' => 'h2','class' => array('element-invisible')))); ?>
```

> Fact 4: You can control the classes applied to each menu ul in the
>   menu region tpl (depending on your theme, presumably).
>
> To add a class to the ul of the main menu, you would modify
>   array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix', 'main-menu')) to array('links',
>   'inline', 'clearfix', 'main-menu', 'new class')).

It actually looks like your referencing code sample from like [this blog post from Koumbit](http://www.koumbit.org/en/articles/drupal-7-inline-menu-item-theming):

> I added the following code to the template.php of my theme, to make
>   both the standard user menu and our custom menu for anonymous users
>   use Drupal's built in theming for inline links:

```
/**
 * Make the user menu inline
 */
function customtheme_menu_tree__user_menu($variables) {
  return '<ul class="links inline clearfix">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

But, I think what you really have to do is examine the theme's `region-menu.tpl.php` and see how it or like `page.tpl.php` is rendering the main menus, every theme is different.

Both `theme_links` and `theme_menu_tree` render *Sets* (collections) of links. Different themers use different functions to the same end.

Another module that can help you figure this out is [Devel](http://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and [Devel_Themer](http://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer). Toggle devel_themer on and select your main menu and it will tell you the theme_function being used and the .tpl file (and overrides possible) in use.

Comment: I'm using the Menu Block Module.  Will those changes work with the blocks from that module?

Comment: it should, install devel_themer and see what theme function you need to call.